# How to create a query for matching multiple data with numbers

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to find whether each estate is close to a pharmacy or not (i.e within 3 km) based on the latitude and longitude given in the database. If the estate is close to one, the estate name should be returned when the query is done. It should be noted that 1 in lat/long counts as 1 km. I have been trying to do this using the Pythagorean theorem using cypher, without success.I have tried this query, and a few variations besides, but none seem to work.

```
MATCH (n), (p)
WHERE n:Estate AND p:Pharmacy AND ((sqrt(((n.Latitude -p.Latitude)*(n.Latitude -p.Latitude))
     +((n.Longitude-p.Longitude)*(n.Longitude-p.Longitude)))<3 AND NOT null) 
     OR (sqrt(((p.Latitude -n.Latitude) *(p.Latitude -n.Latitude))
     +((p.Longitude-n.Longitude)*(p.Longitude-n.Longitude)))<3 AND NOT null))
     RETURN distinct n.Name


CREATE (Estate1:Estate{ Name: "Estate1",Longitude : 1, Latitude: 1, Area: 80, Floor: 5, Elevator: true, Price: 1500})
RETURN Estate1

CREATE (Estate2:Estate{ Name: " Estate2",Longitude : 3, Latitude: 4, Area: 120, Floor: 2, Elevator: false, Price: 2200})
RETURN Estate2

CREATE (Estate3:Estate{ Name: " Estate3",Longitude : 7, Latitude: 3, Area: 200, Floor: 3, Elevator: true, Price: 1000})
RETURN Estate3

CREATE (Estate4:Estate{ Name: " Estate4",Longitude : 9, Latitude: 1, Area: 72, Floor: 4, Elevator: false, Price: 2500 })
RETURN Estate4


CREATE (Pharmacy1:Pharmacy{ Name: "Pharmacy1", Longitude : 4, Latitude: 3})

CREATE (Pharmacy2:Pharmacy{ Name: "Pharmacy2", Longitude : 14, Latitude: 2})

CREATE (Pharmacy3:Pharmacy{ Name: "Pharmacy3", Longitude : 9, Latitude: 7})
```

Comment: In your query Two parts which are `OR`ed looks same, one of it can be removed.

Comment: Also remove `NOT null` part after And. This might be creating done problem

Comment: You can also use Neo4j function to find distance. Read more here: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/spatial/

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Neo4j's native [spatial types](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/spatial/) and [functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/spatial/) instead. They are indexable, so if you save the coordinates as a point type parameter on your nodes and index them, you can perform [spatial index lookups by distance](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/spatial/) which should be both easier to use with Cypher and more performant.

So, assuming you have a `location` spatial point property on your :Pharmacy and :Estate nodes, and indexes on both, you can use the following for an indexed lookup of estates by distance (in meters) from the pharmacy:

```
MATCH (e:Estate)
WITH e.location as estateLocation
MATCH (p:Pharmacy)
WHERE distance(p.location, estateLocation) < 3000
WITH DISTINCT e
RETURN e.name as estate
```